# Can't access a parallel app model in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have two projects parallels to each other:

[image]

They share the same database, as indicated by the picture:

[image]

I need to know if there is a way to display one model from "scalestore-app" into "scalestore-sac".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the same model class for each application, that way they override the table and now I can always access the updated table.